# Upload image and Json using Javascript with axios

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I uploaded a formData with an image and a JSON object using Javascript with Axios. The issue arises when I try to pass the payload to the backend and the values are never received but the image does. I also noticed that if the createStoryAsync uses formData.append for each field, the backend receives all their corresponding values but the fields may be too many to work on each of them.

**FRONTEND
DOES NOT WORK**

```
export async function createStoryAsync(Title, Category, formFile) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    var json = JSON.stringify({Title, Category});
    formData.append("createStoryModel", json);
    formData.append("formFile", formFile[0]);

    await axios.post(`${baseURL}/create`, formData);
```

**Payload:**

```
FORMDATA:
createStoryModel: {"Title":"FADFASD","Category":"fdasfds"}
formFile: (binary)
```

**WORKS**

```
export async function createStoryAsync(Title, Category, formFile) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("title", title);
    formData.append("category", category);    
    formData.append("formFile", formFile[0]);

    await axios.post(`${baseURL}/create`, formData);
```

****Payload:****

```
FORMDATA:
title: 123
category: 12
formFile: (binary)
```

**BACKEND**

**Story Entity**

```
 

     public class CreateStoryModel
        {
            public string? Title { get; set; }
            public string? Category  { get; set; }
        }
```

**Story Controller**

```
        [HttpPost("create")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> CreateAsync([FromForm]CreateStoryModel createStoryModel, IFormFile? FormFile)
       {
...  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> The issue arises when I try to pass the payload to the backend and the
> values are never received but the image does

```
var json = JSON.stringify({Title, Category});
    formData.append("createStoryModel", json);
```

Because the you pass JSON.string to the backend as above, it won't bind value to the model,then  the values are never received .

> the backend receives all their corresponding values but the fields may
> be too many to work on each of them.

If you don't want formData.append for each field, you can  use jquery to get the data

1.add the id to the form:

```
<form id="form"  >
```

2. use the below simply code to create your formData,

```
      var formData = new FormData($('#form').get(0));
```

Comment: Hi Qing Guo, thanks for your help. 1. We do not want to use JQuery. 2 According to your explanation JSON.string can not bind the value to the backend, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi @Peng ,  Do you try `var formData = new FormData($('#form').get(0));` ? await axios.post('${baseURL}/create', formData);